# Entity Framework 6 with ASE 15.7

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sybase, sap-ase

Is ADO.NET Data Provider released with ASE 15.7 supports Entity Framework 6?

And is there any documentation which shows how to create Web.config / App.config with ASE 15.7 + Entity Framework 6?

Comment: we can't answer this. Open the DLL in [telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) and [look if it implements the requirements of EF6](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rebuilding%20EF%20providers%20for%20EF6)

Answer (score 1):

Official Reply from SAP support:

> Currently ASE SDK doesn't support EF 6.0.
> CR# 765581 is the request for this support.
> You can follow KBA#  2484554 to know when this is supported.
> I've updated the Team lead of this request as well.
> Currently .Net 4.5 Ado.Net driver supports EF 5.0.

> There is currently no target SAP SDK Service Pack scheduled for the new feature >request CR 765581. It is being reviewed by our Product Group.  Please mark this >KBA as a Favorite to receive an update when this enhancement is implemented.